# "No viable conversion from..." when working with maps in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am trying to use `lower_bound()` function which is a built-in function in C++ standard library that returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the container whose key is not considered to go before `k`. My understanding is that is used as follows:

```
my_map.lower_bound(key)
```

I have a class `SpeedProfile`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class SpeedProfile
{
public:
    map <int, float> timeSlotMap;
};
```

and I'm trying to call `lower_bound` from another class:

```
vector<SpeedProfile> speedProfiles = isRightDirection ? positiveSpeedProfiles : negativeSpeedProfiles; 


time_t t = time(nullptr);
tm* timePtr = localtime(&t);
uint32_t dayOfWeek = timePtr->tm_wday;
SpeedProfile dayProfile = speedProfiles[dayOfWeek];
int secondsPassed = (int) (dateinMillis) / 1000;

float lower_b = dayProfile.timeSlotMap.lower_bound(secondsPassed);
```

I am getting the following error and I'm not sure how I should proceed.

> No viable conversion from 'std::__1::map, std::__1::allocator > >::iterator' (aka '__map_iterator<__tree_iterator, std::__1::__tree_node, void *> *, long> >') to 'float'

Using `auto lower_b` solves the error warning but I don't think this is the correct way forward.

Comment: You say _returns an iterator_ but write `float lower_b = `. If you want to dereference the iterator to get the `float`, use `->second`.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound

Comment: [What's the difference between “STL” and “C++ Standard Library”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-the-difference-between-stl-and-c-standard-library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you said it yourself, `lower_bound` returns a iterator not a float.

To be precise it returns an iterator to the map *value type*, which is a pair of the key and value (`std::pair<int,float>` in your case). So to get the float you want you write

```
float lower_b = dayProfile.timeSlotMap.lower_bound(secondsPassed)->second;
```

Note this code has undefined behaviour if all the keys are less than `secondsPassed`. In that case the iterator returned would be to the end of sequence value (i.e. `dayProfile.timeSlotMap.end()`) and dereferencing that iterator is an error.